# Organize / categorize forms into named folders?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way to create folders for categorizing and organizing all of our forms? We're starting to get a larger number of these, and as we create more it will be a long list to scroll through.

Would be nice if we could store them in named folders. I can see the need for "Inactive" forms, for example, so we could file those away for future reference / use.

If not a current feature, would be a good feature request, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Cognito Forms support.  We don't have this feature, but it's been requested.  You can add your vote and comments to our public [Idea Board here](https://trello.com/c/z2vJRXuG/177-ability-to-organize-forms-into-folders).